# Spacemacs highlighting empty lines within brackets

Tags: emacs, whitespace, curly-braces, spacemacs

Empty lines are automatically being highlighted within brackets. This behavior only occurs with curly brackets, not parens, etc.

The issue seems to be with smart-parens, but I have systematically disabled all relevant variables associated with smart-parens. None disable this behavior, aside from disabling smart-parens itself.

I should add that the highlighting happens immediately after switching to Normal mode from Insert mode.

I've scoured the forums and I can't find anything related to this issue. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Here's a screenshot of this issue and all the modes I have enabled.]

Comment: This is not related to Spacemacs, vanilla Emacs also has this indicator, and the problem only occurs in cc-mode. Although I didn't find any variables to control it, and the associated face.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Trailing whitespace needs to be set to nil.

1. `Spc-f-e-d` to open up .spacemacs config file
2. Locate `(defun dotspacemacs/init ()`
3. Add `dotspacemacs-show-trailing-whitespace nil` inside this function to disable trailing whitespace inside all buffers

Thank you @TianshuWang for pointing me in the right direction!